# Do any post RoTK stories exist?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I just finished another read through of LoTR and I would like to read about the events of the fourth age. I have read the appendices which offer a quick summary of some events, but is there any sources that expand on these events? (Gondor's war with the evil men, Rule of Aragorn and his sons)

Does not have to be canon or Tolkien necessarily.

Comment: Asking for fanfics is offtopic, but you definitely should read the apocryphal "[The Last Ring-Bearer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Ringbearer)" by Yeskov. It's free, and a fairly faithful English translation is available (endorsed as a good read by several SFF.SE members). Admittedly, the Russian version is marginally more fun to read due to some cultural allusions that are of necessity lost in translation.

Comment: Sorry for this being an inappropriate question, but none the less thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Asking for fanfic recommendations may be off-topic for this site, but there is one relevant work that you ought to check out.  Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately?) it was never finished, but there is some information available.

### The New Shadow

*[The New Shadow](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_New_Shadow)* was a planned sequel to *Lord of the Rings*, which detailed the Fourth Age and the reign of Aragorn's son.  Tolkien ended up abandoning it, but he had this to say about it:

> I did begin a story placed about 100 years after the Downfall, but it proved both sinister and depressing. Since we are dealing with Men, it is inevitable that we should be concerned with the most regrettable feature of their nature: their quick satiety with good. So that the people of Gondor in times of peace, justice and prosperity, would become discontented and restless — while the dynasts descended from Aragorn would become just kings and governors — like Denethor or worse. I found that even so early there was an outcrop of revolutionary plots, about a centre of secret Satanistic religion ; while Gondorian boys were playing at being Orcs and going around doing damage. I could have written a 'thriller' about the plot and its discovery and overthrow — but it would have been just that. Not worth doing.

There is also a [timeline of the Fourth Age](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Arda#Fourth_Age) available, although it doesn't go too deep and most of the events are described in *LOTR*.

Comment: Were those few pages he wrote ever published? Like in a collection or something

Comment: @Shevliaskovic It appears in volume twelve of the "History of Middle-Earth" series, *The Peoples of Middle-Earth*. At least as far as it goes, which is only about a page and a half.

Comment: Oh that's great, and I own that one! I appreciate that the source is Tolkien and not another author.